# How can i update array's element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have array of products in state.allItems. (each product has id, title etc.)
i want to change info about element by button.
i send product's id.

think that i make something wrong in mutations.
action:

```
UPDATE_PRODUCT({commit}, id){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return axios.request({
        url: '`{url}`',
        method: 'put',
        data: {id:id},
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    })
        .then((resp)=>{
            commit('UPDATE_PRODUCT_IN_STATE', resp)
            alert('Товар успешно изменен!')
            console.log(resp)
            return resp;
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error)
            return error;
        })
},
```

mutation:

```
UPDATE_PRODUCT_IN_STATE: (state, id)=>{
    state.allItems = state.allItems.map(i=>i.id===id)
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easy to know what you try to achieve but here:

I guess your map method will return an array that looks like this: `[false, false, true, false...]`
It is because `state.allItems.map(i => i.id === id)` will compare
every item in `state.allItems` and return either `true` or `false` based on whether the current item `id` matches the `id` that is sent as parameter.

Check this out:
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: oh, yes, it's right. but can u say me which method i need to use. i need to update all info about product(object) in my array by it's id

Comment: If you want to update only one item use :
const toModify = state.allItems.find(i => i.id === id);
toModify.name = "new name";

Comment: If you want to replace the object, you can also use :
`const index = state.allItems.findIndex(i => i.id === id);`
`if (index !== -1) state.allItems[index] = <the replacement object>;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using vuex right now. If your "resp" is a new item what I suppose you're going to do is to replace the old item with the same id inside allItems with the new item "resp".

A simple way to archive this is through the [array splice function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

The following should help you to reach your goal.

```js
UPDATE_PRODUCT_IN_STATE: (state, resp) => {
    const { id } = resp;
    const toUpdateIndex = state.allItems.findIndex(el => el.id === id)
    if(toUpdateIndex === -1) return state;
    state.allItems.splice(toUpdateIndex,1,resp);
},
```

Comment: should i send only object's id? or i need send the whole object or only changed properties
?

Comment: @Stanislavkm send the whole object